# Scrapy: how to make a request to scrape a link inside a page

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I already made a question, about this website, but i think i got ahead of facts and now i'm stuck.

The structure of the website is something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="header" colspan="2">something</td>
</tr>

</table>
<br/>
<table> 
<tr>
<td class="header" colspan="2">something2</td>
</tr>

</table>
<br/>
<table>
<tr> 
<td class="header" colspan="2">something3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But inside one of  one of those tables there is a list of members and I need to extract the profile information of each member, but each profile is variable, so the table with its information changes, depending on the privacy settings.

The table i need to scrape is something like this, but with many members:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="header">members</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">Name</td>
                <td class="title">position</td>
                <td class="title">hours</td>
                <td class="title">observ</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="c1">       
                    1.- <a href="http://profiletype1.com" target="_blank">Homer Simpson</a>
                </td>
                <td class="c1">
                    safety inspector
                </td>
                <td class="c1">
                    10
                </td>
                <td class="c1">
                    Neglect his duties
                </td>
            </tr>
<table>
```

I already have most of the code to extract the information from the tables, but now I do not understand how to do the function that allows me to extract the information from the profiles of each member

My spider is defined this way:

```
class Scraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scraper'
    start_urls = ['somesite.com']

    rules = {
    # Rule to extract profile info
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(), restrict_xpaths = ('/table[6]//tr/td[1]')),
                        callback = 'parse_member', follow = False)
}
def parse(self, response):
  # logic to scrape each table

def parse_member(self,response):
  # logic to scrape each profile for every member
```

But when I run the spider, I only get the results of extracting each table inside the main page. But I do not get the data for each user profile.

How can i follow the link for each user profile and scrape the data inside without breaking the code to scrape the tables inside the main page?

Comment: If link to profile follows always the same pattern, it might be better to use `allow` to specify which links to extract instead of `restrict_xpaths`.

Comment: profile has two types, because it depends of the privacy configuration given by the member

Comment: Two types is still a finite and non-changing set which can be enumerated beforehand ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a `Rule` at all, you could do something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    tables = response.xpath('//table[./tr/td[contains(text(), "members")]]')
    for table in tables:
        for href in table.css('tr td a::attr(href)'):
            yield Request(href, callback=self.parse_member_profile)

def parse_member_profile(self, response):
    ...
```